# Users get immediatelly redirected to Auth0 Login page instead of landing on the IndexPage

Tags: auth0, gatsby

I try to create a personal portfolio site with GatsbyJS and want to protect certain areas of my site with a login, to be precise all pages with path `/account` should be proteced. Auth0 provides the protection. However, instead of showing the landing page (where I provide some basic information), the users get redirected directly to Auth0's login page.

I followed the tutorial of jlengstorf (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-vuF2PYHmU&index=2&list=PLz8Iz-Fnk_eTpvd49Sa77NiF8Uqq5Iykx and https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-auth0-app) and I'm quite sure, that I implemented it similar to his solution.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import ContainerUnauthenticated from "../components/containerUnauthenticated"

const IndexPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ContainerUnauthenticated>
                <p>
                    Here is some introducing text, just divs and ps, nothing special
                </p>
                <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <Link to="/account/cv" className="waves-effect waves-default" style={{ color: '#039be5' }} >
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt" />
                            &nbsp;Please login here
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </ContainerUnauthenticated>
        </div >
    )
}

export default IndexPage
```

I also tried `/account` in `Link's` `to` attribute, but this did not work too.

I'd like to show the IndexPage first, hence the user can read the basic information of the landing page and can click on the "Login" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a problem likely in your react routes or somewhere else as to redirect to the Auth0 Login page you have to purposely redirect to the authorization endpoint. Also this could be the result of your index being protected by triggering a unauthenticated event. I hope this helps you in your quest.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react

Comment: Hello @coding-morrison!
Hi folks!

Thank you for your help, you were right! There was an issue in the Auth0 configuration respectively in the file `gatsby-browser.js`. Unfortunately, I called the wrong method there. Hence, if a landing page is required, the method `componentDidMount()` must be called (instead of `componentWillMount()`). Now, the users sees the landing page, can click on the login link and gets redirected to Auth0's login page. 

Again, thank you very much for your hints!!! Kind regards!